# Xcode cannot find 'std' namespace

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I have the following code

```
#ifndef TPSO1_thread_h
#define TPSO1_thread_h

#define _XOPEN_SOURCE

#include <ucontext.h>

struct Thread_Greater;

class Thread {
    ...

    friend struct Thread_Greater;
    friend class Scheduler;
};


struct Thread_Greater : public std::binary_function <Thread,Thread,bool> {
    ...
};

#endif
```

in a .h file. Problem is, when I try to compile it in xcode it says

```
#Error: use of undeclared identifier 'std'
```

In the line

```
struct Thread_Greater : public std::binary_function <Thread,Thread,bool> {
```

Is there any include that I am missing?

Comment: I guess `ucontext.h` doesn't include any headers that declare anything in `std` then, let alone the header `std::binary_function` is in.

Comment: Relying on `uncontext.h` to pull in header content for you is not a good plan. You're header references a template within a namespace, neither of which you have provided with your existing include list. At a minimum add `#include <functional>`, the standard header which provides the declaration for `std::binary_function`.

Comment: Oh i see. I thought the problem was in std, but I was missing the include for std::binary_function. Those compiler warnings are very misleading.

Comment: @Jean-LucNacifCoelho, What else is it supposed to say? You're using a namespace that doesn't exist.

Comment: But isn't the std namespace intrinsic to C++?

Comment: @Jean-LucNacifCoelho *no*.

Comment: @Jean-LucNacifCoelho, There are a couple of ties, but you still have to include the headers to use the types. For example `typeid` returns a `std::type_info`, but you can't use `std::type_info` without including `<typeinfo>`. Other examples include `std::initializer_list`, `std::nullptr_t`, and soon `std::nullopt_t`, and of course `std::size_t` from `sizeof`.

Comment: @Jean-LucNacifCoelho One of my bigger bitches about people that talk of the "language" synonymously with the "standard" (one defines the other, but also defines a rich library  that you can utilize). The core *language* is *not* the standard library. Its a *language*, driven by rules of grammar, defined behavior, etc. You also get a standard *library*. There is a *small* amount of incest between the two, but it is miniscule in comparison to the breadth of each. The standard library is (usually) implemented with the language; the language is *not* the standard library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include the headers for the library components you use. In this case `std::binary_function` is in `<functional>`, so you need this line in your code:

```
#include <functional>
```

---

Just to explain a bit more, the `std` namespace is not built-in to the C++ language (mostly). Unless it's actually declared somewhere in a program then it does not exist as far as the compiler is concerned.

It's even possible to build useful C++ programs that make no use of the standard library. The C++ specification includes a mode that may not even include a standard library: freestanding mode.

If you use something from the `std` namespace without that namespace having been declared in the program then you'll get an error telling you `std` hasn't been declared.

```
int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello\n";
}

main.cpp:2:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'std'
  std::cout << "Hello\n";
  ^
```

If you use something and `std` has been declared, but not the specific member of `std` you're using, then you'll get an error about `std` not containing the thing you're using:

```
#include <utility> // declares std, but not std::cout

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello\n";
}

main.cpp:4:12: error: no member named 'cout' in namespace 'std'
  std::cout << "Hello\n";
  ~~~~~^
```